# Laurent polynomials of the form $p(x)\cdot p(x^{-1})$

Tags: polynomials, arithmetic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Let $R$ be a commutative, associative ring with $1$ and let $\tau: R[x^{\pm 1}]\to R[x^{\pm 1}]$ be the $R$-algebra involution $\tau(x)=x^{-1}.$ Then it is natural to ask which elements of the invariant subalgebra $R[x^{\pm 1}]^\tau$ are of the form $p\cdot \tau(p)$ for some $p\in R[x^{\pm 1}]$.

This problem reduces to a question whether each
$$a_n(x^n+x^{-n})+ ... + a_1(x+x^{-1})+a_0\in R[x^{\pm 1}]^\tau$$ equals
$p(x)p(x^{-1}),$ for some $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n c_ix^i$, which leads to the system of equations:
$$\begin{cases} c_0^2+...+c_n^2=a_0\\ c_0c_1+...+c_{n-1}c_n=a_1\\ ...\\ c_0c_n=a_n.
\end{cases}
$$

I suspect that this problem has been studied already and I am hoping to be pointed in the right direction.
I expect that this system have a solution for algebraically closed fields $R$ (at least when characteristic $\ne 2$), but don't know the proof.
However, the most interesting case for me is $R=\mathbb Z$. I wonder if there is a manageable description of $a_0,...,a_n\in \mathbb Z$ for which the above system has a solution in integers.

Comment: Sounds like an Tate cohomology group $\hat H^0(\langle \tau\rangle, ?)$. The invariant subalgebra is what is fixed by $\tau$ and you are asking for the image of $1+\tau\in\mathbb{Z}[\langle\tau\rangle]$. Just not clear what multiplicative abelian group $?$ to take.

Comment: $(x-i)(x^{-1}-i)$ does not have a constant term.

Also, are you parametrizing $\tau$-invariant polynomials or polynomials $p(x)p(x^{-1})$? If the $\tau$-invariant ones, then how do you show that $1$ and $-1$ have even multiplicity? I think this is at the heart of showing that these two classes coincide over algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @Adam Oh, you are right. I conjecture that the non-zero polynomials of the form $()=()(^{−1})$ read $()=(+^{−1})^()$, $()$ having a constant term and a multiset of roots $\mathcal{O}_r$ as I described i.e. (i) $±1$ each of even multiplicities (ii) $\mathcal{O}_r$ is closed by $z↦1/z$. I must think about a precise statement. Thanks for interaction.